# How do I create a date from this data?

Tags: date, excel-formula

I've exported data that contains a date field but not all fields are dates.
Here is a sample:

```
29/03/2017 12:00:00 AM
30/03/2017 12:00:00 AM
31/03/2017 12:00:00 AM
7/4/2017 0:00
10/4/2017 0:00
11/4/2017 0:00
12/4/2017 0:00
```

I need a formula to create a date in a new cell so I can create pivot tables and analyze data by date.

Using =DATE(MID(E2,7,4),MID(E2,4,2),LEFT(E2,2)) works for the first set of dates (the ones that include AM at the end)

But I get an error on the second set of dates (the ones that do not have an AM)

Using left(cell,2) returns 42 on these cells.  What the heck is this 42?  When I use left(cell,1) it returns 4.  I can't figure out how to create a date out of this field.

Comment: It is because the lower ones Excel can see as a date.  I assume your default short date format is `mm/dd/yyyy`  So it sees `7/4/2017` as July 4th and not April 7th.  so the underlying value is `42920` which is how Excel sees dates.  The upper ones since there is no month 29 - 31 are text and can be parses as such.

Comment: So use this formula to make them all text in the proper order then you can use your formula to parse them all: `=IFERROR(TEXT(--A1,"mm/dd/yyyy"),A1)` where A1 is your first date.

Comment: you can use `day()` , `month()`, `year()`, `hour()`, `minutes()` function to 'extract' the values.. then use `date()` & `time()` to combine them

Answer (score 0):

Looks like excel recognizes your date in multiple formats. Thats why the error. Please try the below formula,

`=MID(LEFT(TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy"),10),4,2)&"/"&LEFT(LEFT(TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy"),10),2)&"/"&RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy"),10),4)`

This formula converts your string to a `dd/mm/yyyy` format and then to `mm/dd/yyyy` format.
[image]